# Uso de variable local no asignada

Tags: c#, bucle-for

tengo el siguiente código en c# y me aparece error al querer imprimir la variable donde acumulo mi resultado. Tengo el mismo para visual basic pero en este no me genero ningún inconveniente

```
namespace Fibonacci_CS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UInt32 primero, segundo, resultado;
            primero = 1;
            segundo = 0;


            for (int x = 1; x <= 20; x++)
                resultado = primero + segundo;
                Console.WriteLine(resultado);
                segundo = primero;
                primero = resultado;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recuerda que en `C#` las llaves `{}` definen el bloque de la instruccion, sino defines ninguna solo tomara unicamente la siguiente linea.

Quizas lo que buscas es lo siguiente

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int primero, segundo, resultado;
    primero = 1;
    segundo = 0;


    for (int x = 1; x <= 20; x++)
    {
        resultado = primero + segundo;
        Console.WriteLine(resultado);
        segundo = primero;
        primero = resultado;
    }
}
```

veras como se enmarca el `for` con las lineas que debe incluir

Comment: En c#, en java, php, javascript... creo que la gran mayoría de lenguajes que usan algún símbolo para delimitar bloques de código tienen esa misma funcionalidad

Comment: excelente gracias!